Можно ли в Дельфи сделать универсальный Lock-ер?
Очень часто приходится делать и\или использовать классы с локом. И каждый из них построен однотипно: есть процедуры Lock\Unlock, функция IsLocked и реализуется всё это через декремент\инкремент FLock. Смысл, я думаю, понятен - чтобы обновления объекта не вызывались во время лока.
Вопрос - можно ли как это автоматизировать изящнее чем передавать в конструктор объект-локер, что будет сам будет рулить этим всем?

Не очень понятно в чем неудобство. Если классов много - можно унаследовать их от общего предка, или интерфейс привнести. Классовые переменные не подойдут? Было бы хорошо увидеть в вопросе пример текущей реализации.

Неудобство в том, что почти всегда у таких классов нет общего предка. Да, они реализуют интерфейс Locker, но всё равно для каждого класса нужно заводит счётчик, функции lock, unclock, islocked и тд.
Т.е много рутинного и дублирующегося кода.

А локер в приложении один или несколько? Вообще можно добавить общего предка вроде TLockableObject = class(TObject). Второй вариант - сделать record с интерфейсом блокировщика и объявить в нужных классах поле с ней. Но Berlin не поддерживает custom managed records, так что надо будет инициализировать в конструкторе.
